# What is IndexError? I keep Getting It

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, syntax-error, python-3.3

Here is my code:

```
quote = input("Enter a Sentence: ")

a = len(quote)
counter = 0
counter1 = 0
reverse = a

print("The Length of the sentence is",a,"characters long!")

for x in range(0,a):
    if str.isspace(quote[x]) == True:
        counter = counter + 1

print("The Length of the sentence is",a - counter,"characters long (excluding space...)!")

for x in range(0,a):
    if str.isupper(quote[x]) == True:
        counter1 = counter1 + 1

print("The number of Upper Case Characters in the sentence is",counter1,"characters!")

print("The number of Lower Case Characters in the sentence is",a-counter1,"characters long!\n")


while reverse >= 1:
    r = reverse
    print(quote[r])
    r = r - 1
```

It's aim is to find everything about that sentence, but the only problem is the 'While' loop at the bottom. It doesn't seem to work, and it's aim is to 'inverse' the sentence. However, it gives my an error which looks a bit like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\ususer\My Documents\Downloads\StringStuff.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(quote[r])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What Am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: use `print(r)` to discover your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is `0`-indexed, so the first character of a string is `str[0]` and the last is `str[len(str) - 1]`. So, since you start with `reverse = len(quote)`, at the end you are doing `quote[len(quote)]`, which is one past the end of the string.

So, you should probably start with `reverse = a - 1` and your loop at the end should look something like:

```
while reverse >= 0:
    print(quote[reverse])
    reverse = reverse - 1
```

Comment: Note also that his current while loop will never exit, as he decrements `r`, not `reverse`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. It only prints the second character.

Answer (score 0):

You have run into the common problem that Python starts indexing from 0, but returns the lenght of a list as a valid integer counted from 1. This results that for any list, `l[len(l)]` will give you IndexError, because a list of length 10 will only have indexes 0...9. 
All you have to do is to initialize `reverse = len(quote)-1`.
You also have to descend your loop variable inside the while loop, so use `reverse-=1` instead of `r=r-1`.